# Vista Console App?

Tags: windows, ruby, windows-vista, console

I'm doing a fair bit of work in Ruby recently, and using

```
 ruby script/console
```

Is absolutely critical. However, I'm really disappointed with the default Windows console in Vista, especially in that there's a really annoying bug where moving the cursor back when at the bottom of the screen irregularly causes it to jump back. Anyone have a decent console app they use in Windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/).

I like the tabbed interface and that copy works properly if text breaks at the end of a line.

Comment: Had to switch the answer after a long time... Console2 is great (as of 2010-03-08).

Answer (score 3):

Are you resizing the console window? I've found that the ruby scripts (irb, etc) that use the readline library don't work correctly with resized console windows (in XP or Vista).

Effectively I believe that the readline library expects the console window to be 80 characters wide, anything else and it goes bezerk. So far I haven't found a way to fix it on windows without giving up other nice features.

Comment: once again, i just want to comment on this - great suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

I have had some pleasant experiences with rxvt (comes with cygwin, does not need an x server running). Putty is also often mentioned as a good alternative.

You could also try to get xterm working :)

Answer (score 0):

[Powershell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx)

> Windows PowerShell is Microsoft's task automation framework, consisting of a command-line shell and associated scripting language built on top of, and integrated with the .NET Framework. PowerShell provides full access to COM and WMI, enabling administrators to perform administrative tasks on both local and remote Windows systems.

Comment: @lomaxx: Powershell isn't a console window - it's a great console app, but i need something to run it in.